# Display points with minimum number in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In Highchart I want to set the number of plot points that are to be shown in the dynamic graph.

For example, if I set the number to 10, only 10 points in the dynamic series will be shown.
I have implemented another graph and it shows only 6 points but I want to display at least 10 points.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)**

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chachart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: "container",
                type: "spline",
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Inverter ~ AC Currents'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    turboThreshold: 2000,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                radius: 5,
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

In the link above, I do not see any line that defines the limit for the number of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `addPoint` in your example works, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint).

So third param (shift) is responsible for removing first point in series. Just add checking if number of points == 10, and then set it to true to remove point.

Comment: Then how do I get the length of the series?

Comment: Check `chart.series[index].data.length`.